# nginx proxy_pass url with GET params conditionally

Tags: nginx, proxypass

I have a url `http://foo.com/banana` and I have another url `http://foo.com/banana?a=1&b=2`

I like that all `/banana` routes are handled by my local nginx, but I'd like any banana routes with GET params to be proxied to `http://bar.com`

so:

`http://foo.com/banana` -> `http://foo.com/banana`

`http://foo.com/banana?a=1` -> `(proxy)` -> `http://bar.com/banana?a=1`

I should note this is **not** for production. I'm trying to redirect api calls to redirect to another server during development.

I've tried to do an 'if args' block but I can't do a `proxy_pass` in an if block.
I thought about doing a rewrite of:
`http://foo.com/banana?a=1` -> `http://foo.com/proxy?a=1`

```
location /proxy {
   proxy_pass http://bar.com;
}
```

But I don't have the right logic for above because `bar.com` is expecting the `/banana` route.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is not for production, you could stick with your original "if" solution. You only need to escape from the "if" block to be able to proxy_pass, which can be easily done with the traditional trick:

```
location /banana {
    error_page 418 = @good_old_fallback;

    if ($args) {
        return 418;
    }
}

location @good_old_fallback {
    proxy_pass http://bar.com;
}
```

Your idea of using another location will also work, so if you prefer it better, you can go with something like this:

```
location /banana {
    if ($args) {
        rewrite ^/banana(.*)$ /proxy$1 last;
    }
}

location /proxy {
    internal;
    rewrite ^/proxy(.*)$ /banana$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://bar.com;
}
```

Comment: Awesome examples!
The second one proved to work better for what I was doing so thanks for taking the time to explain it both ways.